# change associated textbox color using Required Field Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I'm using required field validator to validate textbox.

```
    <tr>
       <td>
           <asp:Label ID="lbllogin" runat="server" Text="Registration ID"></asp:Label>
        </td>
       <td>
           <asp:TextBox ID="txtloginid" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                ontextchanged="txtloginid_TextChanged" TabIndex="1" 
                ToolTip="Enter Registration Id" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
       </td>
       <td>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqloginid" runat="server" 
                ControlToValidate="txtloginid" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*" 
                ToolTip="Enter Registration Id" ValidationGroup="User_login" 
                ForeColor="#CC3300" SetFocusOnError="True"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
       </td>
</tr>
```

Now i want to add color to textbox , how can i do it with required filed validator. i'm using updatepanel. thanks in advance

Comment: Checkout this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196859/change-text-box-color-using-required-field-validator-no-extender-controls-pleas