# Vaidation in POpup Window is not working properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am having an issue in validating popup screen in my project.I am using validation group to validate the controls in popup .Our project standard is showing Red Foreground for controls which are not filled.Its worked in Normal screens but it is not working in popups ( ForeColor color Red )?
Is any way to solve this?
CLICKING ON 'btnExportLE ' button in same window the popup div will show.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnExportLE" runat="server" class="btnNew" Text="Export LE" OnClientClick="returnShowExpPopup();" />
```

**CSS**

```
.popups
{
    position: absolute;width: 550px; height: 430px;border-width: 0px;top: 240px;margin-left: 273px;
    background: #FFF;border-radius: 5px;box-shadow: 6px 6px 7px #4d4d4d;z-index: 10000100; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

### JS Function

```
function ShowExpPopup()
{
document.getElementById('<%= dvExpPopUp.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById("divBG").style.display = "block";
return false;
}

<div id="dvExpPopUp" runat="server" class="popups" style="display: none">
        <div class="popupTop">
            <table width="550px" style="height: 100%">
                <tr style="height: 10px;">
                    <td style="text-align: center; width: 510px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Export LE" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: right; width: 30px;">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClose1" CssClass="lnkcancel" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
                            OnClientClick="Clear();closeInfo();" Text=" X "></asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <table width="550px" style="font: Arial; font-size: small;">
            <tr>
                <td width="10%">
                </td>
                <td width="25%">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMandantCode" runat="server" Text="Mandant Code"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMandantCode" runat="server" class="txtBox" Width="200px" TextMode="SingleLine"
                        MaxLength="3"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RVMandantCode" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" ControlToValidate="txtMandantCode"
                        ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="V2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td width="10%">
                </td>
                <td width="25%">
                </td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="server">
                    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" ValidationGroup="V2" Style="margin-bottom: 0px"
                                Text="Export" class="btnNew" OnClick="btnExport_Click" />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnExpClose" runat="server" Text="Close" class="btnNew" OnClientClick="Clear();closeInfo();"
                                OnClick="btnExpClose_Click" />
                                <br />
                            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="" class="errMsg"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdWaitImage" runat="server" DynamicLayout="true" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
                                <ProgressTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="imgProgress" ImageUrl="Images/loader.gif" runat="server" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblWait" runat="server" Text="Please Wait..." Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="#FE2E2E"></asp:Label>
                                </ProgressTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdateProgress>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: `OnClientClick="returnShowExpPopup();"` should be `OnClientClick="return ShowExpPopup();"` there is a space missing.

Comment: Ok.Popuwindow is working fine.validation is also working .Instead of showing Error message (*) Iwant to show cotrol's foreground as Red. That is not working in popup window controls.

Comment: Have you used anything like Chromes Developer tools to inspect the element and see what sttles are applied to it and where the style is coming from? This will give you abetter indication of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use like below

```
OnClientClick="return ShowExpPopup();"
```

### Edit 1

for changing the fore color of the control here is a similar question on SO
[Change Text Box Color using Required Field Validator. No Extender Controls Please](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196859/change-text-box-color-using-required-field-validator-no-extender-controls-pleas)

Comment: It was my mistake which happend while copying the code. I have used 'OnClientClick="return ShowExpPopup();"' like this in my project ..Popupindow is working fine.validation is also working .Instead of showing Error message (*) Iwant to show cotrol's foreground as Red. That is not working in popup window controls

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Shekhar for the link.Its Woking Fine....

```
function fnOnUpdateValidators()
{
   for (var i = 0; i < Page_Validators.length; i++)
   {
      var val = Page_Validators[i];
      var ctrl = document.getElementById(val.controltovalidate);
      if (ctrl != null && ctrl.style != null)
      {
         if (!val.isvalid)
            ctrl.style.background = '#FFAAAA';
         else
            ctrl.style.backgroundColor = '';
      }
   }
```

}

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(this.GetType(), "val", "fnOnUpdateValidators();");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to display the validation message for pop up in pop itself.
And use seperate validation group for main page and pop up.
Suppose if you are using validationgrp1 for main page then use validationgrp2 for pop up.
It think it will work out.
Thanks & Regards,
Aloy

Comment: Thanks for your response.Actually The Error message is displaying in popup window . But Fore color of controls are not changing if it is not filled.That is my issue .I am using validation only in popup window.