# Show an ASP.NET Validation Summary in a jQuery UI Modal Message

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery-ui

I've made an ASP.NET web form that uses the standard ASP.NET validation.  I'd like to make the error summary show up in a jQuery UI Modal Message as well as below the actual form.

Is it possible to execute the script if the validation finds an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hijack or override the ASP.net page validation function. This removes the need for an extra CustomValidator.
[Here's a description of how to accomplish this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/124682/can-you-have-custom-client-side-javascript-validation-for-standard-asp-net-web-fo/125158#125158).

Keep the validation summary in a hidden `div`, like Mike suggested.
Then in your overridden function, call the original function to do the actual validation and display that `div` as the modal window.

Answer (score 1):

I used the idea in the link provided by GeReV
and here is what I came up with, in case someone needs it:
[Check here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/12/14/part-1-showing-asp-net-validation-summary-in-a-custom-dialog.aspx)

Let me add a note: Don't vote-down this post in case if it has to be a comment. I don't see a option to add comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a CustomValidator.  Set the `ClientValidationFunction` property to be a javascript function that would execute your desired jQuery.

Just for reference, [here's an in-depth look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) at how you can manipulate validators on the client side.

Comment: I'd actually have to write the custom validation function in order to make this work.  If I had to do that I'd just switch to something like jQuery Validation.  ASP.NET validation is just easy and I was hoping to use those validators.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the validation messages in a hidden `div` so that they would fill the `div` on some errors. Then manually show the ui modal specifying the content would be the content of the `div`.