# How to make the error of a RegularExpressionValidator appear next to the control?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Like the question says I want to put the `Error Messsage` of the validator next to the control, not under it, anyone with some ideas?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931573/regular-expression-validator-display-block-rather-than-inline-when-dynamic) is about the error message visibility but they might have the answer by combining several strategies, which include wrapping the error message in a div and using a css class with a lot of rules marked !important.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are quite new to ASP.NET application. I face this problem before.

Please check on your .aspx file, before your `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ......>`, is there a `<br />`? If yes, Just remove it and the Error Message will appear next to the control.

Hope this help...