# Even when the span element has visibility:hidden, it occupies space in FireFox

Tags: css, asp.net

I am working on asp.net webforms. I am displaying a asp:RegularExpressionValidator in a `<td>` element which validates entry in a textbox. When the page loads, it is displayed as a `<span>` element with visibility:hidden. The problem is that in Firefox, it still occupies space, which doesn't happen in IE and Chrome. Because of this the html is not displayed properly in Firefox. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: use display:none instead of visiblity:hidden

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: In my case, it is set by the asp.net control from the code behind!

Comment: Use the approach mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931573/regular-expression-validator-display-block-rather-than-inline-when-dynamic

Comment: Visibility:hidden, does just that Hides the Visibility of the entity. Think of  Harry potter Invisibility cloak, harry was still there just invisible, He was still taking up SPACE.  Display:None removes the element from the Page.  RIP Severus.

Answer (score 1):

"Visibility: hidden;" renders the element but keeps it invisible.
If you intend not to load the element, you should use

```
.someElement { display: none; }
```

This would not even reserve the space for the specified element.

Hope this helps..

Comment: It's strange though that the OP said `visibility:hidden` worked fine in IE and Chrome. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: There must be some mistake. `visibility:hidden` occupies space in Chrome. Not sure about IE.

Answer (score 1):

You should try `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`.

`display:none` means that the tag in question will not appear on the page at all (although you can still interact with it through the dom). There will be no space allocated for it between the other tags.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a different approach... I know that code depends on asp.net... I presume the thing you don't want is to have a bigger spacing because of those validators, or you don't want the layout to be expanding on error highlight, considering that, I'd suggest:

- Make all validator messages having position absolute (I hope you have a container for each field, that one needs to have `position: relative`)
- As each validator have absolute position, won't take more vertical space (it's better to add the code via a css class, which should have something like:

  .validatorMessage { 
  position: absolute;
  left:0;
  top: 2rem /* should be the height of the field */
  }

The only issue is, when those messages fires up, will shorten the available space, but I think is a reasonable tradeoff.

Hope this can help